# VBA - How To Loop Over Sets Of Fiscal Year Dates

Tags: excel, vba

Having an issue with looping over Fiscal Year dates in Excel VBA.

My Goal: Hide columns that have dates greater than today's date.

My Problem: The columns are organized by Fiscal Year (I am 6 months ahead of the calendar year). Therefore the code below does not act like I want it to.

```
Sub Hide_Date_Columns()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("F2:AC2").Cells
    If c.Value > Date Then
        Columns(c.column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

I am trying to fix this problem behind the scenes by adding x = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, (Range("R2:W2").Value)) to my for loop, but I am getting a type mismatch.

```
Sub Hide_Date_Columns()
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Variant
Dim c As Range
Dim DateArray() As Variant
Dim x() As Variant
Dim i As Variant
x = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, (Range("R2:W2").Value))
b = Range("R2:W2")

For Each a In Range("F2:Q2").Cells
    If a.Value > Date Then
        Columns(a.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next a


For Each b In x
    If b.Value > x Then
    Columns(b.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next b


For Each c In Range("R2:AC2").Cells
    If c.Value > Date Then
        Columns(c.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need iterate the range, you cannot use DateAdd with more than one value.

Comment: Was going to say the range itself doesnt support that method or property lol

Comment: Damn lol. Will try your suggestion and will report back.

Comment: Manually did it... Posted code below. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Hutch yes there is a better way to do it but it requires typing a lot more. Using arrays and then storing what columns need to be hid (either in variable(s) or array) and then hiding everything all at once.

Comment: Maybe I'll try that when I have a moment... but for now this works lol

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering. I manually added each DateAdd needed.

```
Sub Hide_Date_Columns()
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Range
Dim f As Range
Dim g As Range
Dim h As Range

u = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, (Range("R2").Value))
v = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, (Range("S2").Value))
w = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, (Range("T2").Value))
x = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, (Range("U2").Value))
y = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, (Range("V2").Value))
Z = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, (Range("W2").Value))

For Each a In Range("F2:Q2").Cells
    If a.Value > Date Then
        Columns(a.column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next a

For Each b In Range("X2:AC2").Cells
    If b.Value > Date Then
        Columns(b.column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If

Next b

If u > Date Then
Columns(u.Columns).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If v > Date Then
Columns(v.Columns).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If w > Date Then
Columns(w.Columns).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If x > Date Then
Columns(x.Columns).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If y > Date Then
Columns(y.Columns).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Z > Date Then
Columns(Z.Columns).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```